# list index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, telegram

I created a Telegram bot with MySQL database. The user can insert and retrieve the orders from MySQL. The telegram bot will display the order details from MySQL when the user inputs the `/select` command. I have attached the MySQL table with two orders.

```
from datetime import datetime
import mysql.connector
import telebot

bot_token = ''

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "",
    database = "telegram",
)

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['select']) 

def select_order(event):
    try:
        my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mysql")
        res = my_cursor.fetchall() # fetch all the results
        mydb.commit()
       
        if(res):
            text = create_message_select_query(res) 
            bot.send_message(event.chat.id, text)
       
        else:
            bot.send_message(event.chat.id, "No orders found inside the database.")

    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        bot.send_message(event.chat.id, "Something Wrong happened... Check your code!")

def create_message_select_query(ans):   
    text = " "
    for i in ans:
        id = i[0]
        product = i[1]
        quantity = i[2]
        date_edited = i[3]
        text += "<b>"+ str(id) +"</b> | " + "<b>"+ str(product) +"</b> | " + "<b>"+ str(quantity)+"</b> | " + "<b>"+ str(date_edited)+"</b>\n"
    message = "<b>Received  </b> Information about orders:\n\n"+text
    return message
             
bot.polling()
```

I encountered an error `list index out of range` when I input the telegram command `/select`.
How do I fix the above error?

[image]

Comment: show the output of `print(i)` written right below `for i in ans:`

Comment: Let's say you have a list called *lst* that is not empty. The valid indexes for *lst* will be -len(lst) -> len(lst)-1. Any subscript outside of that range will induce IndexError

Comment: continue printing out an error list index out of range. Meanwhile, print(i) no outcome displayed.

Comment: "print(i) no outcome displayed" - if `print(i)` gets called but empty - check `print(ans)`

Comment: Received   Information about orders:

 1 | coca-cola | 10 | 11/12/2022
2 | pepsi-cola | 15 | 11/12/2022

Comment: Please [don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also, when your problem is a specific error, post the full stack trace of the error, for the code you've shared.